# How to generate all the possible nodes inside a polygon, if the polygon is represented by its vertices

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, data-structures

If a polygon is represented by its vertices(latitudes, longitudes), is it possible to find all the possible points or nodes(latitudes, longitudes). If so, what kind of algorithm is used. The polygon does not intersect itself and it does not have any holes.

Comment: The set of interior points of a polygon is infinite. So no, it is not possible. Or did you mean something else?

Comment: it is actually possible to find, there is an algorithm called scanline algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote you a pseudocode of the algorithm, I don't think it's perfect, but you can take the idea. Take the vertices of the polygon as an array of pairs of latitude and longitude lines. GSize determines the number of matches in each dimension of the grid. For each point inside the polygon.

```
// Determine the bounding box
function findPoints(NVertices, GSize):
     minX = min(NVertices.longitude)
     maxX = max(NVertices.longitude)
     minY = min(NVertices.latitude)
     maxY = max(NVertices.latitude)

     //Divide the bounding box into a grid of cells
     cellSizeX = (maxX - minX) / gridSize
     cellSizeY = (maxY - minY) / gridSize

//Iterate over each cell in the grid
for i from 0 to gridSize-1:
    for j from 0 to gridSize-1:
        // Step 4: Calculate the center point of the cell
        cellCenterX = minX + (i + 1) * cellSizeX
        cellCenterY = minY + (j + 1) * cellSizeY

        // Check if the Center point lies within the polygon
        if isPointInPolygon(cellCenterX, cellCenterY, polygonVertices):
            // Center point is within the polygon, consider it as a point within the polygon
            output(cellCenterX, cellCenterY)
return

function isPointInPolygon(x, y, Vertices):
isInside = false
j = Vertices.length - 1
for i from 0 to Vertices.length - 1:
    if ((Vertices[i].latitude <= y) != (Vertices[j].latitude > y)) and
       (x < (Vertices[j].longitude - Vertices[i].longitude) * (y - Vertices[i].latitude) / (Vertices[j].latitude - Vertices[i].latitude) + Vertices[i].longitude):
        isInside = !isInside
    j = i
return isInside
```

There is such an algorithm, I'm writing you a kind of script here, I saw it once, it should work.

Comment: Nice effort but why do you answer an incomplete question ?